# How can we synchronize reads and writes to mem cache on app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

How can we make sure only one instance of a JVM is modifying a mem cache key instance at any one time, and also that a read isn't happening while in the middle of a write? I can use either the low level store, or the JSR wrapper.

```
List<Foo> foos = cache.get("foos");
foos.add(new Foo());
cache.put("foos", foos);
```

is there any way for us to protect against concurrent writes etc?

Thanks

Comment: What about this: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/memcache/overview#Safely_Handling_Concurrent_Memcache_Updates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fh. is almost on the right way, but not completely. He is right saying MemCache works atomically, but this does not save you to take care of 'synchronization'. As we have many instances of JVM's running, we cannot speak of real synchronization in terms of what we usually understand when thinking of multi-threaded environments. Here's the solution to 'synchronize' MemCache access across one or many Instances :

With the method`MemcacheService.getIdentifiable(Object key)` you get an `Identifiable` object instance. You can later put it back in the MemCache using `MemcacheService.putIfUntouched(...)`

Check the API at [MemCache API : getIdentifiable()](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/memcache/MemcacheService#getIdentifiable%28java.lang.Object%29).
An `Identifiable` Object is a wrapper containing the Object you fetched via it's Key.

Here's how it works:

- Instance A fetches Identifiable X.
- Instance B fetches Identifiable X at the 'same' time
- Instance A & B will do an update of X's wrapped object (your object, actually).
- The first instance doing a `putIfUntouched(...)` to store back the object will succeed, `putIfUntouched` will return `true`.
- The second instance trying this will fail to do so, with `putIfUntouched` returning `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you worried about corrupting memcache by reading a key, while a parallel operation is writing to the same key? Don't worry about this, on the memcache server both operations will run atomically.

Memcache will never output a 'corrupt' result, nor have corruption issues while writing.